# How to access menu items?

Tags: selenium, node-webkit

I have a fully functional nw.js app running on Ubuntu 20.04. I am able to use ruby's selenium-webdriver gem to access the app's web components (written in angular). I am able to get access to the components on the main window, click on buttons and so on. Works great.

```
require 'selenium'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
```

But I have not been able to access the nw.js menu. I have a MenuItem called "Info" for example and there is no way to click it from the ruby script. The menu works correctly when I click on it manually. But the Selenium ruby script can't seem to access it.

I tried to add a key sequence to get to the MenuItem. Again, works fine manually "Alt-I", but when I use

```
web.driver.action.key_down(:alt).send_keys('i').perform
```

it fails. As far as I can see this line has no effect.

The nw.js documentation has no information about this, or any example code that I can find. I tried google and again no example code that I can see.

If you have this working in ruby or python (I can translate it) please post.

EDIT: here's the relevant menu code:

```
export class MenuService {
    public menubar: nw.Menu;
    private info_menu: nw.MenuItem
    <snip>

  this.menubar = new window.nw.Menu({
            type: 'menubar'
        });

        // add submenu to the menubar
        this.info_menu = new window.nw.MenuItem({
            label: 'Info',
            tooltip: 'Get info',
            key: 'i',
            modifiers: 'alt',
            click: () => {
                this.show_info()
            }
        })
        this.menubar.append(this.info_menu)

 <snip>
 }
```

[image: menu screenshot]

Comment: Please add your code , html , screen shot of menu etc .

Answer (score 0):

Found a sort of, kind of solution. I am not sure if this is the official nw.js method to use.

First run this:

```
  js = %{
     return nw.Window.get().menu;
  }
  puts("jax", JSON.pretty_generate(web.driver.execute_script(js)))
```

This will dump the JSON content of the menu layout. Look in the "items" hash. That's an array of the menu items. Find the menu item you want, in my case it is "Info" which is element 2 in the array. Use the following to click the item:

```
  js = %{
     return nw.Window.get().menu['items'][2].click();
  }
  puts(JSON.pretty_generate(web.driver.execute_script(js)))
```

Note: this is not a complete answer:

- should work for a nested menu item (e.g. File | Quit) but have not tested it